# Paste Only Numbers in Input Field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an Input field in my form. I want to be able to past only numbers in this input field.

**For example:** (Some random characters on my clipboard W123W000)

**Should Paste** = 123000

**Note:** Only works in Chrome Browser

I have been searching online and so far I came up with this but it's not working properly.

```js
var inputBox = document.getElementsByClassName('numbersOnly');
inputBox.onchange = function () {
    inputBox.value = inputBox.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
}
```

```html
<input id="number" type="number" class="numbersOnly">
```

Comment: In Firefox, the change event doesn't seem to fire for `input[type=number]` when the input is not numeric. Maybe because there is no "commit" action when the value is not valid?

Comment: Good catch! I will have to do more investigating on that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `jQuery` for cross-browser compatibility and bind the event `input` to handle every change.

[`Firefox: <input type="number">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number)

> elements automatically invalidate any entry that isn't a number (or empty, unless required is specified).

You can change to `type=text`, but you will lose the numeric keyboard behavior in devices.

```js
var inputBox = $('.numbersOnly').on('input', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="number" type="text" class="numbersOnly">
```

Comment: Hi this won't let me paste the test characters: W123W000. It should strip the letters

Comment: @taji01 exactly, this approach will strip the letters.

Comment: Have you tried it in Firefox?

Comment: @taji01 **Firefox doc:** elements automatically invalidate any entry that isn't a number (or empty, unless required is specified).

Comment: Good to know! I will change the type to text so it will work. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @taji01 you're welcome!